# What Algorithm will Find New Longtail Keywords for *keyword* in PPC

Tags: indexing, match, keyword, pay-per-click

I am looking for the algorithm (or combo) that would allow someone to find new longtail PPC search phrases based on say one corekeyword.

Eg #1  word word corekeyword
eg #2 word corekeyword word

Google search tool allows a limited number vertically - mostly of eg#1 (https://adwords.google.com.au/select/KeywordToolExternal)
I also know of other PPC apps that allow more volume than google adwords keyword tool, 
But I want to find other combos that mention the corekeyword & then naturally sort for the highest volume searched.

Working example of exact match: 
corekeyword:  copywriter  (40,500 searches a month)
google will serve up:  become a copywriter (480 searches globally/month in english)
But if I specifically look up: How to become a copywriter (720 searches a month)
This exact longtail keyword phrase has 300 more searches than the 3 word version spat out by google.

I want the algorithm to find any other highly search exact longtials like: how to become a copywriter
Simply because it was save significant $ finding other longtail keywords after your campaign has been running an made google lots of money.

I don't want a concantenation algorithm (I already have one of those), because hypothetically, I don't know what keywords will be that I want to find.

Any gurus out there?

Becci

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is so much an algorithm problem as a putting-yourself-in-your-potential-customer's-shoes problem.

What need does your product fill?  What question would someone be asking that your product can answer?

There are some good search terms right there.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate different pages for different keywords and compare the SERP position with the number of visitors. Like A/B-split testing for keywords